# Is there a way I can simply use a data annotation attribute to add a JavaScript attribute to a form field?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-validation

I would like to add a `data-other-for` attribute to a text input, to link it to a select, so that it can be used to capture a value not present in the select when the user selects 'Other' in the select. The attribute's code will determine which value or description is in fact 'Other', and if so, enable the text input and maybe make it mandatory.

It seems like the only way to do this is by creating a new helper, because going via a `ValidationAttribute` I can only add preset validation HTML attributes to my text input. Or go large and write a whole new metadata provider.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to implement a custom ModelBinder.

Say, in the select you would have:

```
new SelectListItem(Text = "Other", Value="bind:propertyName", Selected = False);
```

Then in the overriden BindModel, you simply look for `bind:` in the model properties and when found, copy your value from there.

After this, you should be able to add normal validation attributes to your select list.

Comment: I don't want to add validation attributes to my select list. I want to add information attributes to my text input.